# display nested collection using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to display following output (json), the input are from pl/sql cursors, 
my questions:

1. how to display this output?
2. what kind of input expected in order to have this output?
3. how to combine 2 cursor results by using `personId` key?

Thank you

input:

```
personCursor: 
[{personName=a,personId=1}, {personName=b,personId=2}]
*contactCursor*
[{personId=1, firstName==x, phone=123}, {personId=1, firstName==y, phone=234}, {personId=2, firstName==z, phone=345},{personId=2, firstName==w, phone=456}]
**output:**
[
  {
    "personName": "a",
    "personId": "1",
    "contacts": 
            [
                {
                    "firstname": "x",
                    "phone": 123
                },
                {
                    "firstname": "y",
                    "phone": 234
                },
            ]
  },
 {
    "personName": "b",
    "personId": "2",
    "contacts": 
            [
                {
                    "firstname": "z",
                    "phone": 345
                },
                {
                    "lastname": "w",
                    "phone": 456
                },
            ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting output you have to use script something like

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var contactLookup = payload groupBy $.personId
---
flowVars.PersonCursor map {
    ($),
    contacts : contactLookup[$.personId]
}
```

Where payload is `contactCursor` and `flowVars.PersonCursor` is `personCursor`. Given code will combine data using Hashmap lookup. Input will be java in case of pl/sql cursor.

HTH

Comment: what kind of data type for contactCursor and flowVars.PersonCursor ? I set both as json, it only works for 1st  PersonCursor record , get following output:  {
  "output": [
    {
      "personName": "a",
      "personId": 1,
      
      "contacts": [
        {
          "personId": 1,
          "firstName": "x",
          "phone": 123
        },
        {
          "personId": 1,
          "firstName": "y",
          "phone": 234
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "personName": "b",
      "personId": 2,     
      "contacts": null
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Json as well as java is fine. But if you are getting response as Iterator change code as `%var contactLookup = payload map $  groupBy $.personId`

Answer (score 0):

The other way you can do this using 2 map operators and looping though the arrays and constructing the output Json along with filter condition to associate the contacts to right person.
Should be something on the lines below:

```
PersonCursor map(v1,i1) {
   personName": $.personName,
    "personId": $.personId,
    contacts : contactCursor map {
"firstname": $.firstname,
"phone": $.phone
           } filter $.personId == v1.personId
}
```